# jQuery Post Code Working but Callback is Error

Tags: jquery, xmlhttprequest

I have this jQuery code used to submit a form:

```
<div class="action-handler" id="pause-request-handler"></div>
<script>
    $(document).on('submit', '#pause-request', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var form = $(this);
        var handler = $(this).attr('action');

        var datastring = form.serialize();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: handler,
            data: datastring,
            dataType: 'JSON',
            success: function(data) {
                window.location.reload();
            },
            error: function() {
                $('#pause-request-handler').text('Error occurred.');
            }
        });
    });
```

It works as expected, it sends the form and adds the new record without error, but the callback is "error", so instead of the reloading the page on success, it prints error occurred.

With Developper Tools -> Network -> XHR it gives status code: OK

[image]

And the response is "ok" which is echoed in the requested url.

[image]

It's 100% working but why the callback is error?

[image]

Is there something not right with it?

Comment: `OK` response text in not a valid json

Comment: You have `dataType: 'JSON',` so jquery automatically attempts to convert your response from JSON to an object.   Which it can't with `"OK"`.  Remove `dataType: 'JSON',`.

Comment: @User863 Thanks a lot! you saved my day! now it works with json_encode()

Comment: Also note that the AJAX request here seems entirely redundant as you're just going to redirect the page anyway